# Are not templates and codesnippets supposed to get installed with the Catel packages when using the NuGet Package Manager?

Tags: catel

I have added Catel.Core 3.7, Catel.MVVM 3.7 and Catel.Extensions.Controls 3.7 to my Project but does not have the codesnippets. I have looked in `C:\Users\NNUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets` and no Catel folder there. I can neither find any templates.

I got the impression these should be automatically installed, or do I need to install them manually as indicated in the end of this [thread](http://catel.codeplex.com/discussions/349152). Seems to be available [here](http://catelproject.com/download/general-files/) but are those version independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NuGet isn't the right mechanism to deploy code snippets & templates. It only contains the actual binaries when deployed via NuGet.

They should be installed manually as documented [here](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=622641)

The code snippets and templates are mostly version independent, but will always work with the latest version.

*btw. why are you using v3.7? The latest version is 3.9 and 4.0 is about to be released*

Comment: Yes, I'm using 3.7 since that was the previous developer used and I just have taken over the project. SInce I do not know Catel and is also new to .NET and Visual Studio I do not want to do things I do not fully know the consequences of.